# How to set socketTimeOut for MariaDB connection in TypeORM Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mariadb, typeorm

We want to timeout the query after certain threshold. We have tried to add socketTimeout flag at multiple places in below code snippet. Its not working for MariaDB with TypeORM framework in NodeJS. Please help.

```
const { createConnection } = require("typeorm");
const mariadb = require("mariadb");

async function main() {
  const connection = await createConnection({
  type: 'mariadb',
  host: 'hostname',
  port: 3306,
  username: 'db username',
  password: 'db password',
  database: 'db name',
  connectTimeout: 5000, // 5 seconds
  socketTimeout: 10, 
    extra: {
    socketTimeout: 10, 
    queryTimeout: 10
  }
  });

  // use the connection here
  const results = await connection.query('query string');
  console.log(results);
}


main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: Can't you use a `Promise.race` to resolve a promise which finishes earlier, simulating a timeout? Not exactly what you asked but I guess would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

With this configuration, you will in fact use mysql or mysql2 connector.

mysql and mysql2 connectors doesn't permit query timeout. mariadb connector can, but after verification, it is actually not compatible with typeorm due to https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/CONJS-249 (This will be corrected in next 3.1.2 version) after this correction, it would be just as simple as setting

```
  driver: mariadb,
  ...
  extra: {
    queryTimeout: 10
  }
```

So there is actually only 2 workarounds if you use a mariadb server
After creating a connection, you can indicate query default timeout using:

```
SET max_statement_time=
    await connection.query('SET max_statement_time=x'); // x being the timeout in seconds
```

or per query prepending query with "SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=x", like

```
const results = await connection.query('SET STATEMENT max_statement_time=5 FOR SELECT SLEEP (10)');
```

edit:
since 3.1.2 release, it can be done with:

```
const { createConnection } = require("typeorm");
const mariadb = require("mariadb/callback");

async function main() {
    const connection = await createConnection({
        type: 'mariadb',
        driver: mariadb,
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3306,
        username: 'root',
        database: 'testj',
        connectTimeout: 5000, // 5 seconds
        extra: {
            queryTimeout: 10000 // 10 seconds
        }
    });
    // use the connection here
    const results = await connection.query('SELECT SLEEP (10)');
    // or using specific timeout for a query: 
    // const results = await connection.query({ sql: 'SELECT SLEEP (10)', timeout: 5000});
    
    console.log(results);
}


main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
});
```